# Javascript access div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a start script

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.full-info').on('click',loadFull);   
    function loadFull(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $('#pop-up').html(data).show();
        });
    };
});
</script>
<div class="Generalwrapper" >
    <div class="wrapper pop-up" id="pop-up" style="display:none;" ></div>
</div>
```

After Get response i got data in Html format

```
<a href='#' class='close pop-up'></a>
```

So how to hide `#pop-up` div on `.close pop-up` click ?

As from start script `.close pop-up` is not accessible and also from output data `#pop-up` div is not accessible

Comment: It would help if you [fork this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLddVW) and add details (css, missing html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler for the click event can only be assigned after this line of code:

```
$('#pop_up').html(data).show();
```

The HTML is not loaded into the DOM until this line is executed.

Comment: Could you add a reason for `When you specify ID attributes, you shouldn't use dashes (-)` The **[html 4.01 guidelines for id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-id)** are: _ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("\_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")._

Comment: It's just my personal opinion, i.e. style of coding. In JavaScript you can't declare variables with dashes and I just naturally translate that into my naming conventions when giving HTML elements IDs or class names. I've update the answer and removed my faulty assumption.

Comment: I was interested what the standard says. Chapter 7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers  from the [ecma-script-standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf)  states that Identifiers can be composed using Unicode [Connector punctuation Pc](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm) and  ['Punctuation, Dash' Pd](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)  characters which includes hyphen and underscore. But at least in chrome 43 using an hypen returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -` .

Comment: Good to know that it's a Chrome issue, most of my testing is done in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach and bind event as

```
$('#pop-up').on('click', '.close.pop-up', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pop-up').hide();
});
```

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: Not working with dinamic content Please show working example in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pop-up').on("popupbeforeposition", function(event, ui) {

    // bind events like below
    //$('.close.pop-up','#pop-up').off('click');
    //$('#pop-up').on('click', '.close.pop-up', function(){
    //  e.preventDefault();
    //  $('#pop-up').hide();
    //});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code   . add below code in your `$(function() { });`

Learn about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
 $(function() {

   $(document).on('click','.close',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#pop-up').hide();
   });

   $('.full-info').on('click',loadFull);   
    function loadFull(e) {  
      e.preventDefault();
      $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      $('#pop-up').html(data).show();
     });
    };

 });
```

Second Option.( with nearest static parent  )

```
 $('.Generalwrapper').on('click','.close',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $('#pop-up').hide();
 });
```

Comment: As I wrote before .close and pop-up is not accessible from script as .close geting from Get response. Please show in Fiddle how to do that

Comment: this code will work on dynamical created or added element . using ajax or other script

Comment: No, it not working Javascript cant access this class

Comment: I am shure, also alert not work with this code so it meen what script do not starting

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin see my updated answer and make sure you add click event as suggest in my answer

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/q8Qdb/258/  . your ajax url will not work due to cross domain request .  i add .close pop-up dynamical . it is same as your ajax call

Comment: Your example works but with page loading not working. Also i get warning `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` but page is loading well but do not closing popup

Comment: can you update my fiddle with data which you get in ajax response ? and send me link

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#pop-up").hide();
});
```

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!